# How to check whether a linked list is sorted or not using c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, linked-list

How to check whether an array or a linked list is sorted or not given a set of numbers using c++?. Is there a function available to check that?

Comment: [std::is_sorted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35182013/how-can-i-check-if-vector-elements-are-in-order-consecutively

Comment: Top answer on the link Cody Gray just posted. Try to search a bit here with some keywords before asking :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `std::is_sorted` something like:

```
if (std::is_sorted(std::begin(linked_list), std::end(linked_list)) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this stack overflow link hope you get it your answer.

[How do I code a function to test if a linked list is sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608656/how-do-i-code-a-function-to-test-if-a-linked-list-is-sorted)